# WHERE in a UNION statement

Tags: mysql, sql

The question asks:

> Code a SQL statement that uses a UNION between the firstname and
>   lastname of the editor and author tables **where the 5th through 6th
>   digits of the Social Security number are '72'**.
>
> IMPORTANT: **Do NOT use the pattern matching characters, '%' and '_'** in
>   your answer!!
>
> Also be sure to use a string expression to indicate whether or not
>   someone is an author or editor in the result set.

I have this code so far:

```
SELECT 'editor', firstname, lastname
FROM editor
WHERE ssn=
UNION
SELECT 'author', firstname, lastname
FROM author
WHERE ssn= ;
```

But what do I put in the WHERE statement if I can't use pattern matching characters, '%' and '_'

**SSN are written in the DB as 123-45-6789**

Comment: Try substring()

Comment: an alternative to SUBSTRING would be to use a regular expression,  `ssn REGEXP '^.{4}72'`

Answer (score 0):

Using SUBSTRING satisfies the requirement that says your solution should not include any quotes or wildcards. The function's first specifies the expression being searched, the second argument specifies the starting position (5) and the third argument specifies the length of the sub-string (2).

```
SELECT 'editor', firstname, lastname
FROM editor
WHERE SUBSTRING(ssn, 5, 2) = '72'
UNION
SELECT 'author', firstname, lastname
FROM author
WHERE SUBSTRING(ssn, 5, 2) = '72'
```

Comment: ...or we could do use a regular expression  `WHERE ssn REGEXP '^.{4}72'`

Comment: Adding a few words to your solution would improve your answer.